# insert a value to object add key was not worked

Tags: c#

Hi all I have  a object like below

```cs
dynamic obj = new
{
    Translations = new
    {
        test="",
    }
};
```

In this code I need to add more like `test=""` in c#

expected output

```cs
dynamic obj = new
{
    Translations = new
    {
        test="",
        ds ="",
        dsfd=""
    }
};
```

How can I do that I tried with add key not worked

Comment: *"not worked"* is not a problem description. You need to specify exactly what happened.

Comment: If you're trying to add new members to a previously declared object, check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject

Comment: You are not adding properties to an existing object. You are creating a new object having more properties than the previous one.

Comment: please, don't use dynamic unless you _have_ to. i'm pretty sure that, whatever you're trying to achieve, there's a much better way than dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This work

```
dynamic obj = new
{
    Translations = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "test", "" },
    }
};
obj.Translations.Add("ds", "");
obj.Translations.Add("dsfd", "");
```

**This won't work**

```
var obj = new
{
    Translations = new
    {
        test="",
    }
};

obj.Translations = new
{
    test="",
    ds="",
    tedsfdst="",
}
```

Because anonymous type properties are read only and cannot be set. Also, you can't treat `Translations` as a dictionary and add new properties to it, unless you define it as dictionary.